# What regex match this pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP `preg_match_all` to parse patterns like: `key1: value1, key2: value2` I reach to this regex `~([\w-_]+)\s?:\s?([^,]*)~i` it works as spected and the returned array is `[['key1: value1', 'key1', 'value1'], ['key2: value2', 'key2', 'value2']]` using the `PREG_SET_ORDER` arg.

BUT if I want to match text that contains a `,` so to use the text must scape with a backslash `\,` is there a way in regex to skip the `[^,]` breaker if it's `\,`?

Comment: is this JSON by any chance (`{key1: value1, key2: value2}`) ? If so, just use `json_decode($str)`

Comment: @MartinKonecny is right. You should use a parser that was made for the job. If you have formatted the data in this way yourself then you should choose a format that PHP can parse. There is no point in reinventing the wheel when there are solid solutions out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use alternation operator to match escaped comma greedily.

```
~([\w-_]+)\s?:\s?((?:\\,|[^,])*)~i
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pJ0rF8/2)